# Improving inequality $(\int X(x) Y(x) \,dx) \leq (\int |X(y)| \,dy) Y_{\max}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Want to improve the following inequality: $(\int X(x) Y(x) \,dx) \leq (\int |X(y)| \,dy) Y_{\max}$

Looking to replace $Y_{\max}$ with something that will give a tighter bound. Everything else needs to stay the same. The inequality is saturated when $Y(x) = \operatorname{sign} (X(x))$.

There are the following conditions:

$X(x), Y(x)$ are real functions

$$\int X(x)\, dx = 0$$

$$|X(x)| \leq 2$$

So the inequality is not terrible if for example

$$X(x) = \tan^{-1}x, \text{ and } Y(x) = e^{-x^2}$$

but if $Y(x)$ is unbounded, like $Y(x) = x^2$ then the $Y_{\max} = \infty$ really spoils things.

Comment: You're basically asking to improve the $(p,q)=(1,\infty)$ version of Holder's inequality. Even with the the integral condition for $X$ not much can be done. In the unbounded case, you're out of luck.

Comment: Spot on with Holder's inequality. I suspect you're right, that in the most general case it can't be improved. But in cases where the left hand side is finite, still with an unbounded Y(x), there may be an interesting improvement?